# What is ReferenceError and when its counted

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I m trying to send json data via ajax.but I m getting

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#pwd").val();          
        authenticate(email, password);
    });
});
function authenticate(email, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "authenticate.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,         
        data: '{"email": "' + email + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
        success: function () {

                      }
    })
}
```

Comment: You have not included jQuery.

Comment: You have missed jquery library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include jQuery on the site.  Try adding the following script to access jQuery from a CDN at the begining of the page's `head` section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your head tag

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The error may cause because of jquery conflict,If you already included `jquery`

Try [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

`$` in there is about jQuery which is a javascript library that simplifies javascript usage. In order to use jQuery, you must include it into your page e.g.:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But the place is important, it must be before other `<script>` tags which contains jQuery functions(starting with `$` or `jQuery`).